# How to find only the top most instances of search in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

> `<html><table>...<table>...</table>...</table><table>...</table>...</html>`

For example, if I use soup.find_all('table') for the above soup, I will obtain three tables. I want to make it such that it will not dig deeper into the soup after it obtains the first instance of table and will try to find the next instance of that table after the current instance. In other word, it will return the first table with the table nested inside and the second table. I wish to know what would be the most efficient method of carrying out this course of action.

Right now, I'm handling it with by doing:

```
from copy import deepcopy
tables = soup.find_all('table')
reduced_tables = deepcopy(tables)
for table in tables:
    if list(filter(lambda x: table !=x and table in x, tables)) != []:
        reduced_tables.remove(table)
```

Comment: Something like `soup.find_all('table', limit=3)` ?

Comment: @t.m.adam Unfortunately, the number of tables is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:  Use the `recursive` argument in `find_all` to select only direct descendants of a tag.

Option 2:  Use a lambda in `find_all` and filter by `find_parent` to select tags that are not descendants of a certain tag.

Example:

```
html = '''
<html>
<table>table 1</table>
<div><table>table 2</table></div>
<table>table 3<table>table 4</table></table>
<html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 

tables = soup.html.find_all('table', recursive=False)
print(tables)

tables = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and not tag.find_parent('table'))
print(tables)
```

Output:

> `[<table>table 1</table>, <table>table 3<table>table 4</table></table>]`
>
> `[<table>table 1</table>, <table>table 2</table>, <table>table 3<table>table 4</table></table>]`

The 1st option didn't select table 2 as it's not a direct descendant of 'html', but the 2nd option returned all 3 top tables.

If you want to remove nested tables (table 4) use the `decompose` method, eg:

```
for table in tables:
    for tag in table.find_all('table'):
        tag.decompose()
print(tables)
```

> `[<table>table 1</table>, <table>table 2</table>, <table>table 3</table>]`

Comment: I actually wanted to extract the topmost all tables which don't have tables as parent so that I can parse them.

Comment: This will only work when table is at the top level of the soup. Recursive kwarg means that it only checks the top level of the soup, not that it checks the top level of the search object.

Comment: Why don't you try the 2nd method?